# Nokia 820 will not connect to LTE

Tags: nokia-lumia-820

I have an 820 with ATT and just this weekend I was able to use my phone over LTE. Now it just says 4G and I cannot create a hotspot with it. I haven't done anything to my plan with ATT. Any help?

Comment: Were you able to create a hotspot before?

Comment: Yeah I was. Worked perfectly

Comment: have you tried doing a soft reset? btw. afaik 4G = LTE